# How can I adjust the labels on a number-line (to show inequalities) such that the dimension of the .png file (to be download) produced has same size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, labels, standalone

Hello Community Members,

I am working on creating graphs for school students and I was making number-line(s) for a school project.
Note that I am only using LaTeX to create graphs, so I download the .png file and use it for my content.
While creating number-line(s), I encountered a problem when the range of the line is more extensive, that is, -40{to}40 and -60{to}60. It is an easy task when the range is comparatively small but for a large range, the labels overlap each other.

Is there a solution to this problem?
I am sharing my work which I learned from this great community.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}

 \usepackage{pgfplots} \usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots,xcolor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}


\pgfplotsset{%
compat=newest,
tick label style={font=\tiny},
label style={font=\small},
legend style={font=\small},
axis x line = center,
axis y line = center,
every axis/.style={pin distance=1ex},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=none,
inner axis line style={<->},
xmin=-60,xmax=60, ymin=0, ymax=1,
xtick distance=5,
%xticklabels={-60,-55,-50,-45,-40,-35,-30,-25,-20,-15,-10,-5,0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=none,
inner axis line style={<->},
ymin=0,ymax=1,
xmin=-43,xmax=43,
xtick distance = 5,
axis line style = thick,
%major tick style = thick,
%i am using the following if necessary
%x tick label style = {font=\tiny}
%xtick={1,2,3},
%xtick style={},
%xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: The result of the code given]

Comment: The most simple solution would be to show less labels, e.g. use `xtick distance=10`. Of course you can add minor ticks add needed, if this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks! But having xtick distance of 5 is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `TikZ` you can draw your own number line. I have created a corresponding command that you can use for this. I encourage you to play with the different parameters so that you get the result(s) you want in each case.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}

\newcommand\drawNumberLine[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % draw arrow from -arrowLength/2-0.5  to  arrowLength/2+0.5
        \draw[latex-latex,thick] (-#1/2 -.5,0) -- (#1/2 + .5,0);
        % draw ticks with label
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextStep}{#2+#3}
        \foreach \x [count=\c] in {#2,\nextStep,...,#4} {
            % scale \x to arrow length
            % (x - from_min) * (to_max - to_min) / (from_max - from_min) + to_min
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xPos}{(\x - #2) * (#1/2 - -#1/2) / (#4 - #2) + -#1/2};
            % draw tick
            \draw[thick] (\xPos,-.1) -- (\xPos,.1);
            % tick label above or below? (based on \c which starts at 1)
            %  - even: below
            %  -  odd: above
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yPos}{ifthenelse(mod(\c,2)==0,-.3,.3)}
            % \x < 0: shift a little bit to the left (-.12)
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xPos}{ifthenelse(\x<0,\xPos-.12,\xPos)}
            % set tick label
            \node[font=\footnotesize] at (\xPos,\yPos) {$\x$};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% here are the labels always below
\newcommand\drawNumberLineLabelsBelow[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % draw arrow from -arrowLength/2-0.5  to  arrowLength/2+0.5
        \draw[latex-latex,thick] (-#1/2 -.5,0) -- (#1/2 + .5,0);
        % draw ticks with label
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextStep}{#2+#3}
        \foreach \x [count=\c] in {#2,\nextStep,...,#4} {
            % scale \x to arrow length
            % (x - from_min) * (to_max - to_min) / (from_max - from_min) + to_min
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xPos}{(\x - #2) * (#1/2 - -#1/2) / (#4 - #2) + -#1/2};
            % draw tick
            \draw[thick] (\xPos,-.1) -- (\xPos,.1);
            % tick label position
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yPos}{-.3}
            % \x < 0: shift a little bit to the left (-.12)
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xPos}{ifthenelse(\x<0,\xPos-.12,\xPos)}
            % set tick label
            \node[font=\footnotesize] at (\xPos,\yPos) {$\x$};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\drawNumberLine%
    {8}%   arrow length
    {-40}% start point
    {5}%   step wide
    {40}%  end point

\drawNumberLine%
    {8}%   arrow length
    {-60}% start point
    {5}%   step wide
    {60}%  end point

\drawNumberLine%
    {8}%   arrow length
    {-20}% start point
    {2}%   step wide
    {20}%  end point

\drawNumberLine%
    {8}%  arrow length
    {15}% start point
    {5}%  step wide
    {95}% end point

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\drawNumberLineLabelsBelow%
    {15}%  arrow length
    {-40}% start point
    {5}%   step wide
    {40}%  end point

\drawNumberLineLabelsBelow%
    {15}%  arrow length
    {-60}% start point
    {5}%   step wide
    {60}%  end point

\drawNumberLineLabelsBelow%
    {15}%  arrow length
    {-20}% start point
    {2}%   step wide
    {20}%  end point

\drawNumberLineLabelsBelow%
    {15}% arrow length
    {15}% start point
    {5}%  step wide
    {95}% end point
\end{document}
```

Some results:

[image: -40 to 40 with step wide 5]
[image: -60 to 60 with step wide 5]
[image: -20 to 20 with step wide 10]

Some results where the label changes between above and below:

[image: -40 to 40 with step wide 5]
[image: -60 to 60 with step wide 5]
[image: -20 to 20 with step wide 10]

**NEW:** 15 to 95

[image: 15 to 95 with step wide 5]
[image: 15 to 95 with step wide 5]

Comment: Amazing. Useful. Can we use the same when the range is from 15 to 95?

Comment: @UrmilakaVicky I have extended the command. It is now possible to specify start and end point separately.

Comment: Thank you very much!